# Pause a workflow 2 days before start date

Tags: date, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I have a leave workflow which is working fine with no issues

What I want to do is to pause the workflow 2 days(48 hours) before start date of the workflow/leave request

When applying for leave you supplier a start date and the end date, just before the initiator goes on leave the workflow should pause\let the line manager know 2 days before going on leave.

Could someone assist me in doing this in a nintex workflow 2013

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this, first you need to calculate a date based on the start date .. Use the date calculation action to -2 from the start date.. You cam then place a pause in the workflow until that date and send notifications.. A better way of doing it and more robust. Would be to record the date -2 from start date in the content type as a hidden field. Then have a site workflow scheduled to run every morning and cycle through all pending leave requests looking for dates that fall on this day. If the -2 date falls on the day of site workflow execution then post msg to manager to inform them of their staff leave in 2 days time.

For further Nintex related questions please post them to the http://community.nintex.com website